# Swift 4: UIImagePicker delegate methods not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImageView that has my "profile image" inside. When I tap on this, it calls a function that presents my `UIImagePickerController`. This works fine. My issue is that my delegate methods simple aren't being called. When I add breakpoints, it doesn't hit them at all. I have used the exact same method elsewhere in my project and it works fine so there's nothing wrong with my info.plist file. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you...

```
extension ChatLogController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        profileImageView.image = image
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func handlePresentImagePicker() {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using an instance variable of your `UIImagePickerController` instead of local variable.

Comment: can you post ChatLogController code . how you are calling handlePresentImagePicker method . The above works like a charm for me

Comment: @Vinodh My controller literally has a UICollectionView and some keyboard notification observers. I've commented all of these out try see if it's something to do with them. No luck so far

Comment: did you try @BadhanGanesh and Chels MCKay solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the issue was that I was using a custom transition (a transition that involved me being able to swipe right to dismiss my controller). Once I commented all of the code related to that, everything worked fine. Very unfortunate that I have to get rid of my transition but hey, it now works!

Comment: I'm glad it's now working, but I know of no reason a custom transition *should* impact calling a controller's delegate. Maybe you might find a way to do both, now that you've narrowed things down to a specific piece of code.

Comment: @dfd I'm guessing it has to do with the UINavigationControllerDelegate method as they both require it. It's a strange one but you're right, I'm sure there's a way to have both now that we've narrowed it down to the one thing